# Chain of transformations based on generic types

Tags: c#, design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

I'm thinking about a chain, that will allow me to perform a set of transformations with data type changing from transformation to transformation. So far I've got something like this:

```
public abstract class TransformationStep<T, TY>
{
    public abstract TY Execute(T input);
}

public class Times2<TY> : TransformationStep<int, TY>
{
    public Times2(TransformationStep<int, TY> next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }

    public TransformationStep<int, TY> Next { get; set; }

    public override TY Execute(int input)
    {
        var res = input * 2;
        return Next.Execute(res);
    }
}

public class ToString<TY> : TransformationStep<int, TY>
{
    public ToString(TransformationStep<string, TY> next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }

    public TransformationStep<string, TY> Next { get; }

    public override TY Execute(int input)
    {
        var res = input + "!!!";
        return Next.Execute(res);
    }
}
```

The only problem I see is the end chain type, where I can't convert T to TY.

```
public class End<T, TY> : TransformationStep<T, TY>
{
    public override TY Execute(T input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Do you have any solution? Also what do you think about this design and do you know any good materials on stuff like that?

Comment: Did you mean `class End<T> : TransformationStep<T, T>`?

Comment: This looks hauntingly familiar: [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) ... [TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2?view=net-6.0), [ActionBlock<TInput>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-6.0) - _"do you know any good materials on stuff like that?"_ - have a look into those links.

Comment: @Sweeper I didn't know I can do that :) Thanks

Comment: Free example : https://dotnetfiddle.net/POnbk7

Comment: Async Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uw360H

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want transformations:

```
public abstract class TransformationStep<TIn, TOutput>
{
    public abstract TOutput Execute(TIn input);
}
```

And if you want to just return input type, then it is possible to create another method with return type:

```
public abstract class TransformationStep<TIn, TOutput>
{
    public abstract TOutput Execute(TIn input);

    public abstract TIn ExecuteWithoutTransformation(TIn input);
}
```

**Dataflow**

If you want to connect chains of data into pipeline or graph, then you can use [TransformBlock](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2019/06/05/tpl-dataflow-in-net-core-in-depth-part-2/).

**What is about Chain of Responsibility pattern**?

As wiki says about "[Chain of Responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)":

> In object-oriented design, the chain-of-responsibility pattern is a
> behavioral design pattern consisting of a source of command objects
> and a series of processing objects.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) Each processing object contains
> logic that defines the types of command objects that it can handle;
> the rest are passed to the next processing object in the chain. A
> mechanism also exists for adding new processing objects to the end of
> this chain.

Your code looks similar, however, code and goal of chain responsibility pattern is slightly different. It does not make transformations, **it gives object to the next processing object in the chain**.

So one of the variations of code of chain of the responsibility pattern can look like this:

An abstraction of desired behaviour of chain of the responsibility pattern:

```
public abstract class MyHandler<T>
{
    private MyHandler<T> Next { get; set; }

    public virtual void Handle(T request)
    {
        Next?.Handle(request);
    }

    public MyHandler<T> SetNext(MyHandler<T> next)
    {
        Next = next;
        return Next;
    }
}
```

And let us imagine that we are publishing house and we want that each property of article should be validated.
So, concrete implemetations of handling article can look like this:

```
public class OnlyNewArticleValidationHandler : MyHandler<Document>
{
    public override void Handle(Document document)
    {
        if (document.DateCreated.Year < DateTime.Now.Year)
        {
            throw new Exception("Only new articles should be published.");
        }

        base.Handle(document);
    }
}


public class AuthorValidationHandler : MyHandler<Document>
{
    public override void Handle(Document document)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(document.Author))
        {
            throw new Exception("Author is required.");
        }

        base.Handle(document);
    }
}


public class NameRequiredValidationHandler : MyHandler<Document>
{
    public override void Handle(Document document)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(document.Name))
        {
            throw new Exception("Name is required.");
        }

        base.Handle(document);
    }
}
```

And `ArticleProcessor` would look like this:

```
public class MyChainAticleProcessor
{
    public void Validate(Document document)
    {
        var handler = new NameRequiredValidationHandler();
        handler.SetNext(new AuthorValidationHandler())
            .SetNext(new OnlyNewArticleValidationHandler());

        handler.Handle(document);
    }
}
```

And it can be run like this:

```
new MyChainAticleProcessor().Validate(
    new Document { Author = "Author 1", Name="Name 1" }
);
```